# Setting ether value in uint

Tags: solidity

I have a contract that looks something like this:

```
contract Contract {
    uint public money = 2.5 ether
    
    constructor(...) payable {...}

    function setMoney(uint _money) public {
        money = _money;
    }
}
```

What to do if I want to set the value of money to 0.2 ether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2.5 ether` translates to `2500000000000000000` (which is 2.5 * 10^18) wei.

**The actual value stored in the integer is the wei amount.** The `ether` unit is usually used just to make the code more readable and to prevent human errors in converting decimals.

See [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/units-and-global-variables.html#ether-units) for more info.

---

So if you want to set the value to `0.2 ether`, your can pass `200000000000000000` (which is 0.2 * 10^18) to the `setMoney()` function.